# golang webservice crashes unexpectedly without error

Tags: go, net-http, redigo

I'm developping a webservice with golang. It uses the net/http package and others packages like github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql and redigo (redis).
I have no problem when I develop it, no bugs.
When I put it on a server in production as a service in back ground (i.e. : launched with ./myProgram &).
The problem is that after a few times, which is never the same : it can be a few minutes or a few hours, it just crash. The service doesn't appear anymore in netstat : it is down.
I look the memory/CPU consumption/opened tcp connections, there's nothing anormal. 
I also log information on errors and requests on my service in a file, but there is nothing anormal, it just crashes.

If you have any idea,please tell me. Or any idea on the way I can track the error.

Comment: It may be giving you an error message, but you would have no way of seeing it as you aren't piping the output anywhere.  If you start it with `nohup ./myProgram &` it will run in the background but put all of the output in the file `nohup.out`, and then once it crashed you could look at the file and see if there is an error message.

Comment: Obviously no one here is going to be able to debug your webservice for you and obviously you have a bug which is resulting in a fatal panic (no recover)... Find your way to a specific programming problem and you'll surely find help but there's not much to do here. As far as catching your error goes, you can use a defer/recover pattern to implement what acts like an application level exception handler (catch block). Then log your error and use that information to write an actual question.

Answer (score 2):

You mention that this only happens when running on a production server.

Could it be the case that the process is being killed when you disconnect your login session? If so, you want to either use a proper startup script, or at least start it with **nohup**

```
nohup ./myProgram &
```

See [this answer at serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/311593/keeping-a-linux-process-running-after-i-logout) for more details.

Comment: Thank you ! With nohup, my service doesn't crash anymore !